# apt-get broken after banana pro power off

Tags: debian

My banana pro (similar to raspberry pi) got shutdown during installation owncloud server via apt-get because of the power loss in the building. When I rebooted it says, that
`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
I tried running this command, but the error is:
`dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0007' for reading: Input/output error`
The os it is running is bananian, based on debian 8. Is there any way to fix this error, without reinstalling the whole os?

Answer (score 0):

Its very possible that the SD card has suffered from some corruption.  This has happened to me before, and re-imaging the card resolved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case. It happened to me before and I re-imaged the card, but I'd rather not do this again, cause I have set up some servers there and don't want to go through all that stuff again, if it was possible to avoid.